# NUnit 3 - retry not being called on fail

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, nunit

I have a question about the NUnit retry attribute
We are using

```
NUnit 3.12.0
NUnit3TestAdapter 3.17.0
C# and Selenium
```

This is a typical feature file

```
Test.feature
    Scenario Template: 01 Test footer options - Homeowner
      Given we set the destination to the homepage
      When  we select footer option "1"
      Then  we should see the url "tester" and title "test page"
```

This is the hook

```
Hooks.cs      
        [BeforeFeature(Order = 1)]
        [Test, Retry(2)]
        public static void BeforeFeatureTab(FeatureContext featureContext)
        {
            etc
        }
```

And here we have were the fail is being captured

```
        public void AssertUrlContains(string comparing, IWebDriver driver)
        {
            var currentUrl = driver.Url;
            try
            {
                WriteToReport(Status.Pass, "Pass: URL is correct");
                Assert.That(currentUrl.Contains(comparing));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteToReport(Status.Fail, "Fail error: " + ex);
                Assert.That(false);
            }
        }
```

Now I thought the Assert.That(false) would trigger a retry, but it is now. Can anyone see what I got wrong or missed pleased.
Thanks
Kev

Comment: Have you tried using `Assert.Fail` rather than `Assert.That`? I think `Fail` throws a specific exception which may be what the retry logic hooks into. Never used this before though so just an idea :)

Comment: I recently moved from Fail to That

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you didn't tag it, I'm assuming you are using SpecFlow. While I'm not that knowledgeable about it, I've learned a bit from helping folks who use NUnit with it. That said, here's what I think...

The `BeforeFeatureAttribute` translates into an NUnit `OneTimeSetUpAttribute` (formerly `TestFixtureSetUpAttribute`, called before any tests are run. OTOH, the `TestAttribute` indicates that the method **is** a test case. IOW, you are saying that the same method should be called by NUnit to initialize the fixture **and** as a test. That's probably leading to an exception being thrown.

In NUnit, unexpected exceptions are not treated as failures but as errors. An error is typically something that is wrong with your test rather than the system you are testing, so it is handled differently. In particular, only failures are retried, while errors are not.

Note also that NUnit knows nothing about SpecFlow, so if it's a specflow exception, that will be treated as an error like any other exception.

Your best bet is to stop using the same method as both a test and for initializing a fixture.

Comment: Thanks Charlie, I will look into that